# I want to run two audio sources through my headphones

Tags: audio, logitech-headset

I have a gaming headset that I use with my PS4 and would like to run music from my laptop into the audio line while using it with the PS4 as well.

The headset just plugs into the 3.5mm jack in the controller.

The headphones have separate mic and audio lines and I bought a small adapter for that, but I was wondering if I could also run music from my laptop into the audio line so I could quietly play background music but still hear the game sound and chat above all.

This pertains to a Logitech G230 headset if that makes a difference.

Comment: You could use a mixer console.

Comment: would you know of a small and cheap one to recommend?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/CE-Compass-Stereo-Y-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B00APEI7OC/ref=sr_1_57?ie=UTF8&qid=1413776696&sr=8-57&keywords=audio+y+adapter

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can combine 2 audio sources into one. Usually that's done in a mixer, but if you really only want to add 2 audio lines together and don't care too much about audio quality, [a Y cable like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00APEI7OC) should be lightweight enough to work with your setup. Make sure you get a cable that has the male and female parts the right way around, and that you don't get a stereo splitter, or a cable that just separates audio in from audio out - it's easy to buy the wrong thing.

Comment: Using a "Y" cable is a common but bad advice for connecting two audio sources to one speaker/headphones.  Neither output will see the correct impedance that it's expecting.  See http://ask.metafilter.com/167454/Can-I-use-one-set-of-headphones-for-two-audio-sources and #11 of   http://www.hometheaterforum.com/topic/189885-can-you-hook-up-two-audio-sources-to-one-speaker-system/

Answer (score 0):

Audio Source combination is possible by using some small gadgets. Without gadgets, it may not be possible. To Combine Two Audio Sources Into One Headphone, some mentioned gadgets you may need like this

1. Rolls Mixer
2. Y Splitter Mini Stereo (2 to 1)
3. External USB Stereo Sound Adapter
4. Multiple-input Headphones
5. Dual Headphone Jack
6. Audio Mixer 2 Input 1 Output
7. 2 Optical Inputs into 1

You will feel real happiness when you can combine two audio sources into one headphone successfully.

Information Source:
https://swipeonidea.com/combine-two-audio-sources-into-one-headphone/